# What is difference between CSS em and ch units?

Tags: css

What is difference between CSS *em* and *ch* units?

I have been using *ch* in my stylesheet, but *em* seems more common. What is the difference between them?

I understand that 20ch would give enough space for 20 zeroes. I don’t understand what em is. Does it give enough space for 20 M's or is it 20 x fontsize, i.e. size 16 font would give 320, but 320 of what unit? I don't get if they are almost the same or completely different.

Comment: *em* is the font-size of the font, which is traditionally the width of a capital M (thus *em*). *ch* is the width of the number 0 in the font.

Comment: I will recommend you checkout w3schools for better explaination

Comment: Is there something you don't understand from the documentation? See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#lengths, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: What ***exactly*** don't you understand?  What exactly ***do*** you understand?  How do you want us to answer this question beyond copying and pasting the spec definition of both units?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan So I understand that 20ch would give enough space for 20 zeroes, I dont understand what em is, does it give enough space for 20 M's or is it 20 x fontsize, i,e size 16 font would give 320, but 320 of what unit. I don't get if they are almost the same or completely different.

Comment: It is 20 x font-size, where font-size is [defined here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size). Since font-size itself can be relative (and defined in `em`s), I can't answer your question. Generally, it's the size of the M glyph of the font used, when that glyph has the font-size specified. Of course, you can try all of this out for yourself by simply creating an HTML page and setting the CSS appropriately.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have been tried using eM but I just dont understand your answer, if ch is size of '0' in font, why is not em the size of 'M' in font - in practical terms what is the difference between this and your font-size explantin?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I've looked at all the answers and also your comments on them and I got the feeling that you want using `em` and `ch` units mainly for `width` or `height` properties.

> [...] they are not good for setting a field width then?

And from my perspective, I would not recommend that.

---

**CH-Units**

<del>First of all, I've never worked with `ch` before and honestly I do not see any real use for it *- maybe an `input` for the year, so that there is always the width for four numbers, but not more -* because it never tells you exactly how wide an element will end up.</del>

I changed my mind and now I see a good real use for `ch`. :)

The example of an `input` for the year, so that there is always the width for four numbers, will persist. But `ch` is also very useful for correctly defining the text width of a paragraph.

With pixel, relative or percentage values it is very difficult - *especially for a responsive design* - to set the perfect text width per line including spacing for a paragraph. However, this can be a liability for the user experience on the website. An abstract by Atlassian Design is a perfect match:

> Set the reading environment to suit the reader. Wide lines of text are difficult to read and make it harder for people to focus. While there is no right way to measure the perfect width for text, a good goal is to aim for between 60 and 100 characters per line including spacing. Setting an optimal line length breaks up content into easily digestible blocks.
>
> *Source: [Atlassian Design](https://atlassian.design/foundations/typography#line-length)*

This is where `ch` can be used perfectly as a unit. For a better view, you can look at the examples at the end.

But now finally to the definition of `ch` ;)

As often been said, `ch` refers to the width of the `0` character to its font size.

As example: The body has a `font-size: 16px` and the `0` character has a width of `10px` from the selected font-family, then `1ch` equals `10px`. And even that is still inaccurate, because e.g. `italic` or `bold` can change the width of the character.

---

**EM- & REM-Units**

As also often said, `em` *- and to bring one more player in -* also `rem` are relative to the `font-size`.

Where `rem` is always relative to the root element `font-size`, `em` is relative to the `font-size` of the own element or the last parent element *(can be also the root element)* with a `font-size`.

As `em` example: Only the `body` has a `font-size: 16px;` and the element got no `font-size` himself, then `1em` equals `16px`. If a parent of the element or the element himself got a `font-size: 20px;`, then `1em` equals `20px`. `em` units can also multiply upon themselves.

As `rem` example: The `body` has a `font-size: 16px;`, then `1rem` equals `16px`. Even if the element himself or a parent element got a `font-size: 20px;`, `1rem` still equals to the `body` settings of `16px`.

> [...] if ch is size of '0' in font, why is not em the size of 'M' in font [...]

`em` was originally based on the typographic measurement of the current font `M` character but that is already outdated. As you can see now, it always references to a "fixed start-value" and not the width of a character.

---

**Recommended usage**

As I said, from my perspective I would not recommend to use `ch`, `em` or `rem` for `width` or `height` properties. These units are more useful for "textual" properties.

Some examples:

- All `h2` should be four times as big as the text: `font-size: 4rem;`
- All `p` should always have a `margin` of a half line: `margin-bottom: 0.5em;`
- The `line-height` of elements should be 20% greater than the `font-size`: `line-height: 1.2em;`
- A `input` for the year, should always have the `width` of four numbers: `width: 4ch;`
- The text width of a `p` should always have a width of 80 characters per line including spacing: `width: 80ch;`

> but pixels are not flexible when dealing with different devices

For this, as a conclusion, I would advise you to simply work with percentages `width: 80%;` or the viewport width and viewport height `height: 100vh; width: 100vw;`. Or at least always with a maximum value: `width: 1000px; max-width: 100%;`.

---

Here are a few snippets *- just for the examples with `width` properties -*  for a better understanding:

**`em` - Relative to the font size of the own element or the last parent element with a font size**

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  width: 1em;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.em-0-5 {
  width: 0.5em;
}

.em-10 {
  width: 10em;
}

.fs-10 {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.parent {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.parent div {
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<p>1em (body font-size * 1 = 16px)</p>

<div></div>

<p>0.5em (body font-size * 0.5 = 8px)</p>

<div class="em-0-5"></div>

<p>10em (body font-size * 10 = 160px)</p>

<div class="em-10"></div>

<p>10em from 10px own element font-size (element font-size * 10 = 100px)</p>

<div class="em-10 fs-10"></div>

<p>10em from 0.5em parent font-size (body font-size * parent font-size * 10 = 80px)</p>

<span class="parent">

  <div></div>

</span>
```

**`rem` - Relative to font-size of the root element**

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.parent {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.parent div {
  width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<p>10rem (body font-size * 10 = 160px)</p>

<div></div>

<p>5rem in a parent element with font-size 20px (body font-size * 5 = 80px)</p>

<span class="parent">

  <div></div>

</span>
```

**`ch` - Relative to width of the "0" (zero)**

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input {
  width: 4ch;
}

div {
  width: 20ch;
  background: lightgray;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.ch-1 {
  width: 1ch;
}

.ch-5 {
  width: 5ch;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<p>4ch (space of 4x zero character)</p>

<input type="text" value="2018" />

<p>20ch (space of 20x zero characters)</p>

<div>0000000000000000000000000</div>

<p>Also 20ch (space of 20x zero characters)</p>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et </div>

<p>1ch (space of 1x zero character)</p>

<div class="ch-1">00000</div>

<p>5ch from font-size 32px (space for 5x zero characters with a font-size of 32px)</p>

<div class="ch-5">0000000000000000000000000</div>
```

Comment: *input for the year, should always have the width of four numbers: width: 4ch;*


– Doesn't that imply that all numbers will be the same width as the zero? I doubt this will be the case in all fonts you will find out there.

Comment: The __width: 4ch;__ ensures that all 4 entered numbers will be visible (without a horizontal scrollbar) because the expectation is that the zero is usually the widest of numbers. If you enter 1111 in some fonts it will be much narrower than 4ch, the goal is just to make sure there is enough width to show all characters. You can center the text if the font is variable width and it's more usable and esthetically pleasing for strings of shorter widths.

Answer (score 5):

I usually use `em` & `rem`. It's an easier way of make things responsive and depends of the font-family you choose and not on a specific character.

From [MDN `<length>` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length):

> `ch` - Represents the width, or more precisely the advance measure, of
> the glyph "0" (zero, the Unicode character U+0030) in the element's
> `font`.
>
> `em` - Represents the calculated `font-size` of the element. If used on
> the `font-size` property itself, it represents the *inherited* font-size
> of the element.

```html
<h1>How em works</h1>

<h2>Default values</h2>
<p style="font-size: 1em">I am 1 em on a default browser (10px)</p>
<p style="font-size: 2em">I am 2 em on a default browser (20px)</p>
<hr>
<h2>Inherit values</h2>
<div style="font-size: 18px">
  <p style="font-size: 1em">I am 1 em depending on my parent element font-size (18px)</p>
    <p style="font-size: 2em">I am 2 em depending on my parent element font-size (36px)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer until the w3schools reference. It is usually frowned upon in SO since they are historically inaccurate. point to the Moz  one like @Mike McCaughan has in above comment

Comment: @happymacarts you are actually 100% correct. I just have that bad custom of clicking the first link and it usually is w3s. Thanks, will edit

Comment: I did look at w3c schools before posting question but I didn't and I still don't understand the answers

Comment: @PaulTaylor both of this units a relative units. This means it depends on one or another thing. Those values are posted above.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO 'it depends on one thing or another', sorry that means nothing to me.

Comment: @PaulTaylor one thing = ch - Represents the width, or more precisely the advance measure, of the glyph "0" (zero, the Unicode character U+0030) in the element's  font.

Comment: @PaulTaylor another thing = em - Represents the calculated font-size of the element. If used on the font-size property itself, it represents the inherited font-size of the element.

Comment: Hmm, Im sorry everyone keeps saying the same thing without explaining it, I dont understand difference between font-size and width. I dont understand when used to set the width of a textfield if em and ch give approximate same width or not

Comment: @PaulTaylor in that case, i would recommend you to watch some videos on fonts and the units css have. Other way would be if you experiment a little with it.

Comment: Okay but I don't understand why nonone here is capable of actually explaining the difference rather than just cutting/pasting existing answers

Comment: @PaulTaylor i think you are having some problems understanding how em works. I made a small snippet on this answer so you can si how it works.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO thanks, maybe the confusion is that im not trying to set fontsize but width of a field (i.e a textfield), is it appropriate for that ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor yes, you can use it where ever you want

Comment: @PaulTaylor i hope my answer helped you. Hope you can accept it, unless you have any other question. Thank you

Comment: It doesnt help that much because it is being used to change font size, I dont understand how it fits in with field width, nor do I understand why em is generally better than ch

Comment: But... what *is* `font-size`? I had an economics professor who used “schmoos” as units. When a student asked what a schmoo was, she said, “A fluffy widget”. Funny, but not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

They're completely different.

One *em* is equal to the font-size (in pixels) of the parent element. Pixel font size refers to the *height* of the letters in pixels. So if you haven't changed the font-size of the HTML element, the default size of most things is 16px, so one *em* is 16px height. 2em would be 32px height, etc.

Rems are far easier to use than ems IMO (as a Rem unit will always refer to the root/HTML element font-size).

Comment: so if they measure height, they are not good for setting a field width then ?

Comment: While you _can_ use em units to specify width, its not very intuitive. If you want to specify exactly how many characters can be on one line, stick to ch units. Personally I find pixels the easiest to work with.

Comment: but pixels are not flexible when dealing with different devices

Comment: and ch is only '0's width, I have a bounty to award but I cannot award it without getting a more complete answer.

Answer (score -2):

Two things to add to Gerardo's answer:

1. There is a difference in browser support: `em`'s will be supported by any browser used today but the `ch` unit is [calculated slightly different in IE11 and is missing support in Opera Mini.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=ch-unit)
2. `ch` units are always based on the "0" character whereas `em`'s are relative to their respective parents font-size.

Comment: 2. please expand on what this means 'respective parents font-size', isnt it always based on the 'M' character, doesn't ch measurement change depending on what font size is being used ?