# How to adjust textbox width based on input that has fixed number of characters but font size may vary?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm **receiving a text from a server response**:

"AC-8D-9A-7E"

and the text has a **fixed number of characters** of **11** as above and I want to display it on a textbox in HTML.

However, what I want is that, initially **the textbox has a width of 0px** and when I received the text from the server, I will then **append it to the textbox** where the **width of the textbox** is roughly equal to the **width of the text**:

[image]

How do i **set the width of the textbox so that it is roughly the width of the text**?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

#code {
    border-color: black;
    width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "container">
    <input type = "text" id = "code" disabled>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("code").value = "AC-8D-9A-7E";
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I comment out the #code segment css, the textbox will be looking like so:

[image]

Therefore, how do i **retrieve the rough width** of the **textbox** so that it is **roughly the same as the width of the text?**

**Edit: I do not need to consider situations like paste or delete events mentioned in other post as the textbox for me just serve as a display purpose**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ch` unit. `1ch` is approximately equal to the width of 1 character. Since you know the length of the input value is going to be 11 characters, you can set the width of it to be `11ch`.

So when you get the response from the server, you can set the width to be `11ch`. Although you could make it `12ch` and make it look a tad bit better (or you could add padding to the input)

```
#code {
    width: 11ch;
}
```

The accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649169/what-is-difference-between-css-em-and-ch-units) gives a great explanation of the difference between `ch` and `em`. Something you may want to consider.

Comment: Great Sagar, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Use the size attribute that specifies the width of input in characters. I used 11 since your display results has 11 chars. Also, I recommend that you use some padding for input field.

```
<input type="text" size="11" id="code" disabled />
```