# Why do we need 'ch' units when we have 'em' in CSS

Tags: css

`ch` (short for character) is the width of a zero `0` character, `em` is the width of an `M`.

I've known about em dashes (and n dashes) in typography, and in CSS it's useful for defining relative lengths.

What I don't understand is why introduce a new `ch`, surely it's basically around 0.7 of an `em`, depending on the font family? They're both relative to the particular font's character width, so why two, and why zero? Is there any functional advantage (something you can do with `ch` that you can't with `em`), or is it just that zero is typically nearer an average character width?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between CSS em and ch units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649169/what-is-difference-between-css-em-and-ch-units)

Comment: *em is the width of an M.* --> it's not. em is relative to the font-size and it controls the height not the width

Comment: @TemaniAfif Aaah, right, thanks. Makes sense, then. Confusing for someone who has worked in print! https://stackoverflow.com/a/15827146/623519